# Second Derivative of One Function With Respect to Another Function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, chain-rule

I am studying the relationship between two similar functions:

$$ F(g(x)) =  k_1 \int_{0}^x  g(x) f(x) dx$$
$$ F(h(x)) =  k_2 \int_{0}^x  h(x) f(x) dx$$

I am interested in properties of the graph constructed using the first function as the x coordinate and the second function as the y coordinate.  So I am interested in calculating derivatives of F(h(x)) with respect to F(g(x)).

I think that I have the first derivative:

$$ \frac{dF(h(x))}{dF(g(x))} = \frac{k_2h(x)}{k_1g(x)}$$

I derived this with the chain rule and the fundamental thm of calculus.

It shouldn't be that difficult, but I can't seem to calculate the second derivative.  I found a source that suggests that the answer should be

$$ \frac{d^2F(h(x))}{dF^2(g(x))} = \frac{k_2h(x)}{k_1^2(g(x))^2} \frac{\alpha_h-\alpha_g}{xf(x)}$$

where

$$ \alpha_g = \frac{dg}{dx}\frac{x}{g}; \alpha_h = \frac{dh}{dx}\frac{x}{h} $$

Any/all assistance much appreciated.  Thanks, Eric

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: You can define: $$ X(u) = k_1\int_0^ug(t)f(t)dt \quad , \quad Y(u)=k_2\int_0^uh(t)f(t)dt$$ Then $dX/du = k_1 g(u)f(u)$ and $dY/du = k_2 h(u)f(u)$, so $$\frac{dY/du}{dX/du}= \frac{k_2h(u)}{k_1g(u)}$$

Comment: If you imagine $Y(u)$ to be invertible and define $r(y)=Y^{-1}(y)$, you can define $\beta(y) = X(r(y))$, so then you calculate $\beta'(y)$ and $\beta''(y)$ using the derivative rule for inverse functions:  $r'(y) = 1/Y'(r(y))$.